# Lazily split Iterable on condition

Tags: python

I'm having problems trying to create a function that lazily separates an iterable into sub-iterables given a condition.

Here's what I have so far

```py
def split_on_condition(
        seq: t.Iterable[T], condition: t.Callable[[T], bool]
) -> t.Iterable[t.Iterable[T]]:
    curr = []
    for i in seq:
        if condition(i):
            curr.append(i)
        else:
            yield curr
            curr = []
    yield curr


foo = ('a', 'b', 'c', '', '...rest')
print(list(split_on_condition(foo, bool)))

# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['...rest']]
```

So this *works*, which is nice; but the problem is that `curr` is a *list*, rather I want it to be lazy evaluation so that I could use an arbitrarily large sequence as input.

```py
from itertools import repeat

for _ in split_on_condition(repeat('oops, infinite loop'), bool):
    pass
    # Program will crash here :(
```

Comment: Please don't add solutions inside the question. This is what answers are for... If another user helped you can up-vote and accept. Alternatively if you built on an answer for a different solution, you can post answers to your own questions - just not directly inside the question

Comment: Ahhh, I was getting confused as to why my edit was getting reverted. Cheers for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import typing as t
from itertools import islice, tee

T = t.TypeVar("T")

def split_on_condition_gen(
    seq: t.Iterable[T],
    condition: t.Callable[[T], bool],
    keep_condition: bool = False,
) -> t.Iterable[t.Iterable[T]]:
    itr1, itr2 = tee(seq)
    current = 0
    for item in itr2:
        if not condition(item):
            yield islice(itr1, 0, current)
            if not keep_condition:
                # Toss out the item that gave failed the condition
                # We default to None to avoid a StopIterationException
                next(itr1, None)
            current = 0
        current += 1
    yield islice(itr1, 0, current)
```

The `tee` function, which returns a tuple of n independent iterators is important, as some iterables are `generators`, meaning that once you call their `__next__` they're exhausted, and wouldn't work with `islice`.

This version doesn't assume the input is indexable, althought it will still consume the `seq` if it's a generator.

```py
>>> from this import s as seq_
>>> condition = lambda x: x != ","
>>> indexable = ["".join(i) for i in split_on_condition_gen(seq_, condition)]
>>> indexable
['Gur Mra bs Clguba', " ol Gvz Crgref\n\nOrnhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.\nRkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.\nFvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.\nPbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.\nSyng vf orggre guna arfgrq.\nFcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.\nErnqnovyvgl pbhagf.\nFcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.\nNygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.\nReebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.\nHayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.\nVa gur snpr bs nzovthvgl,", "ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.\nGurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.\nNygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.\nAbj vf orggre guna arire.\nNygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, ", "g'f n onq vqrn.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, v", " znl or n tbbq vqrn.\nAnzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"]
>>> generator = [
...     "".join(i) for i in split_on_condition_gen((x for x in seq_), condition)
... ]
>>> assert indexable == generator
```

Comment: Looking great! I was thinking of calling ```next``` n times to single iterator instance if it's guranteed to be iterated in sequence. If so, just having single instance would save memory - I believe.

Comment: Cheers. By all means test and break my function as much as you'd like and comment (or just suggest edit) any improvements or problems; I only tested it lightly with some generators I had lying around for my own projects but I could definitely see this breaking apart at the seams with some more complex input.

Comment: Updated what I was talking about, would that work nicely with your data working with? I found that ```islice``` completely consumes and stops iterator passed as parameter, that might be causing a problem.

Comment: Fantastic solution jupiterbjy, from my tests your updated solution seems to work with any iterator I've tried to throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

For *subscriptable iterable* that implements `__getitem__`, save range then return a generator that iterates given range.

```py
def split_on_condition_gen(seq, condition):
    def inner_gen(range_: range):
        for n in range_:
            yield seq[n]

    last = 0
    current = 0

    for item in seq:
        if condition(item):
            current += 1
        else:
            yield inner_gen(range(last, current))
            last = current
```

As it checks until condition breaks, it's not completely lazy, but at least it can handle large input as it won't consume extra memory until you really need those.

```py
>>> from this import s as seq_
~~ ZEN OF PYTHON GOES HERE ~~

>>> condition = lambda x: x != ','
>>> output = split_on_condition_gen(seq_, condition)
>>> output
<generator object split_on_condition_gen at 0x000002602C1ECEB0>

>>> list_output = list(output)
>>> list_output[2]
<generator object split_on_condition_gen.<locals>.inner_gen at 0x000002602C1ECEB0>

>>> list(list_output[2])
['l', ',', ' ', 'e', 'r', 's', 'h', 'f', 'r', ' ', ...]
```

---

However, for *iterables* without `__getitem__` implemented - for ones like this:

```py
class NonIndexAble:
    def __init__(self, initial: str):
        self.source = initial
        self.list_ = list(initial)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            return self.list_.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration()
```

Will raise errors like this:

```py
>>> non_index_able = NonIndexAble('aaabaaaaba')
>>> condition = lambda x: x == "b"

>>> for part in split_on_condition_gen(non_index_able, condition):
...     for item in part:
...         pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 11, in inner_gen
TypeError: 'NonIndexAble' object is not subscriptable
```

First I thought we could use `itertools.islice`, but found out that it consumes iterator passed, shown like this:

```
except StopIteration:
    # Consume to *stop*.
    for i, element in zip(range(i + 1, stop), iterable):
        pass
```

Rather, as most use-case of this generator would be nested `for` loop, it will run inner-generators in sequence they've created.

For that case, we could just have single *generator instance* and have `counter` variable for 'cursor' location. Then we can get values by skipping from `counter` to `start` and yield from `start` to `end` index and leave generator as-is, not consuming completely like `islice` does so next 'block' could continue with same *generator instance*.

```
counter = 0

def inner_gen(seq_, start, end):
    nonlocal counter

    for _ in range(counter, start):  # Skip from counter to start
        next(seq_)

    for _ in range(start, end):  # yield from start to end
        yield next(seq_)

        counter = end
```

Full implementation:

```py
def split_on_condition_gen(seq, condition):
    seq_copy, seq_current = tee(seq)
    counter = 0

    def inner_gen(seq_, start, end):
        nonlocal counter

        for _ in range(counter, start):  # Skip from counter to start
            next(seq_)

        for _ in range(start, end):  # yield from start to end
            yield next(seq_)

            counter = end

    last = 0

    for idx, item in enumerate(seq_current):
        if condition(item):
            continue

        yield inner_gen(seq_copy, last, idx)
        last = idx + 1

    yield inner_gen(seq_copy, last, idx + 1)
```

Test:

```py
>>> non_index_able = NonIndexAble('asdf adsfa ds sdfdf adf')
>>> condition = lambda x: x != ' '

>>> for part in split_on_condition_gen(non_index_able, condition):
...     print("Part start")
...     for item in part:
...         print(item, end=' ')
...     print("\nEnd")
Part start
a s d f
End
Part start
a d s f a
End
Part start
d s
End
Part start
s d f d f
End
Part start
a d f
End
```

Comment: Your answer is fantastic for Iterables that are indexable, very close to what I needed. Sadly not all Iterables are indexable, so this solution would be perfect for strings/lists but not work for any generic Iterable.

Comment: Mybad, couldn't even think of non-indexable cases, helpfully, there is ```itertools.isslice``` for these cases. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Your last solution does't seem to be cooperating. If you try with `('a', 'b', 'c', '', '...rest')` for example with a condition of `bool` (ie not empty) then we don't get the last element of rest. The indices of the slices aren't cooperating

Comment: As I only have up to 90 mins per day access to pc here, I couldn't perform more tests - my apology. I'll update with fixed one tonight.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use external modules you might harness [more_itertools.split_at](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_at). Consider following example, which takes subsequent integers and split on multiplies of `10`:

```
import itertools
import more_itertools
blocks = more_itertools.split_at(itertools.count(1),lambda x:x%10==0)
block1 = next(blocks)
block2 = next(blocks)
block3 = next(blocks)
print(list(block1))
print(list(block2))
print(list(block3))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

[more-itertools is available through PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/)

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking the time but I had already taken a look at more_itertools and from what I could tell split_at also creates a list as a buffer. See [source](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/88841e9f83ea523ccb1076f0eff10a23a4e24c70/more_itertools/more.py#L1199)